# I have an object and need to access a component of it

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is an odd question and there is a lot of code that isn't included, but I feel with the given information it is pretty straight forward.  I think I have been working too many hours and my brain just gave up so I need help clearing this up.  I have this object called post and when I print(post) I get:

```
<Post: 0x7fa483466610, objectId: dpXjaGqLxd, localId: (null)> {
ACL = "<PFACL: 0x7fa48364eb20>";
caption = "this is a caption";
imageFile = "<PFFile: 0x7fa483656a10>";
user = "<PFUser: 0x7fa4835cd9e0, objectId: hrC0uOpbnI>";
}
```

I'm basically trying to access caption.  Let me know if more code is needed.  I am working with Parse and Swift.  I am hoping that simply by showing the output, I can access caption easily.  I tried post.caption and it doesn't work, while post.ACL does.  I feel like I should be able to access it since I can print this off then caption should be accessible.  Sorry for the dumb question I think my brain turned off a couple of hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you write the class for the post object? I'm assuming you didn't or you would know how to access it's data.

Perhaps caption is a private variable, in that case there should be a getter that returns the value of caption.  Try

```
post.getCaption()
```

Comment: Under Swift getters and setters are generally not written with the prefix "get" or "set", respectively. That's not so say that people always stick to that rule, just that it's more likely to just be `post.caption`. Also, it's more likely to be a property than a function since you can have property observers and computed properties that perform the same tasks as traditional getter and setter functions.

Comment: Someone else wrote it and I added caption to it.  I just don't see how I can print it to the console but not to a label.  I'm still learning but normally if I can print something to console it means I can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have any access to it. When you dump an object, that gives you its internal state, which is not related to its external state. You should just check for an available property or method with a similar name - if there isn't one, it's probably inaccessible.